# list the devices associated with logical volumes without using lvm2 package commands

Tags: linux, lvm, device-mapper

I want to list all the physical volume associated with logical volume.

I know `lvdisplay`, `pvscan`, `pvdisplay -m` could do the job. but I don't want to use these commands. Is there any other way to do it without using lvm2 package commands?

Any thoughts on comparing the major and minor numbers of devices?

Comment: The kernel numbers for a LV are not related to the base device(s). They can even change from one boot to the next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

If you accept `dmsetup` as a non-lvm package command (at openSUSE the is a separate package `device-mapper`) then you can do this:

```
dmsetup table "${vg_name}-${lv_name}"
```

Or you do this:

```
start cmd: # ls -l /dev/mapper/linux-rootfs 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 27. Jun 21:34 /dev/mapper/linux-rootfs -> ../dm-0

start cmd: # ls /sys/block/dm-0/slaves/
sda9
```

Comment: @captain My `/dev/mapper/linux-rootfs` **has** been created with LVM. `dmsetup` uses just the part after `/dev/mapper/`. The LV `rootfs` in the VG `linux` gets the DM name `linux-rootfs`.

Comment: @ Hauke Laging Let me correct it I created volume named 'test' using dmsetup and tried  command ls /sys/block/dm-0/slaves/.I am not seeing any output.

Comment: @captain And your `test` is `dm-0`?

Comment: @captain Strange. I am not familiar enough with the sysfs details in order to explain that. You could make that a separate question.

Comment: My mistake.ls /sys/block/dm-0/slaves/ worked for me.

Comment: I've noticed that checking /sys/block/*/slaves/ may only show a single pv reference if a lv is smaller than a single pv. This is even if there are multiple pvs making up a given vg.

Answer (score 10):

Folks , If you certainly needs to dive inside it then you can give thoughts on comparing Major and minor number

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-3010:~$ sudo dmsetup ls
vgpool-lvstuff  (253, 0)
```

I created this logical volume using disk sda1

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-3010:~$ sudo dmsetup deps vgpool-lvstuff
1 dependencies  : (8, 1)
```

(8, 1) gives me the (major,minor) number of disk on which lvm is dependent which I will compare using following command.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-3010:~$ sudo cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
8        0  488386584 sda
8        1     305368 sda1
8        2    3150112 sda2
```

Answer (score 3):

List all mappers and get all information for each identifier in one line using native commands:

```
for file in $(ls -la /dev/mapper/* | grep "\->" | grep -oP "\-> .+" | grep -oP " .+"); do echo "MAPPER:"$(F=$(echo $file | grep -oP "[a-z0-9-]+");echo $F":"$(ls "/sys/block/${F}/slaves/");)":"$(df -h "/dev/mapper/${file}" | sed 1d); done;
```

Result like as:

```
MAPPER:dm-0:sdd1:/dev/mapper/luks-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 916G 487G 384G 56% /media/whk/Secure1
MAPPER:dm-1:sde1:/dev/mapper/luks-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 916G 487G 384G 56% /media/whk/Secure2
```

The las out is a `df -h` command.

Thanks to @hauke-laging for the comprension of the structure.